# XOR encrypt file on mac

Tags: macos, encryption, xor

I have an xml file that I was looking to do simple encryption on which I then download in an IOS app and decrypt.

I was looking at possibly using XOR encryption. I have managed to sort out the decryption in objective-C but was wondering if anybody knows a simple way to take an xml and encrypt using XOR (and a key) on a MAC.

Comment: That *really* is simple encryption (even Michelangelo imagined better schemes).  Use the built-in symmetric encryption libraries to give you better results with little more code.

Comment: If you really want a simple XOR encryption, then look at a stream cypher (the official name for XOR encryption).  RC4 is simple and very easy to program, though not fully secure.  Otherwise use AES in CTR mode.

Comment: @trojanfoe It's probably less code, and is very likely to be well tested. XOR encryption does seem to offer little benefit if other schemes are already implemented. AES and otherwise RC4 are plenty fast too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the responses - In the end I went with ads-256-cdc encryption using RNCryptor for iOS and openssl on terminal

Answer (score 0):

"XOR Encryption" is a little vague. Any stream cipher could be considered "XOR" since that is how the key stream is applied to the plaintext to make the ciphertext.

If what you mean is "repeatedly XORing a key to the plaintext to make the ciphertext" (a.k.a the Vigenere cipher), then you're already done, because the decryption function is the same as the encryption function.

(And if that is what you're talking about, I hope that it's just for your own education or amusement and not for any production code. The Vigenere cipher does not provide any amount of protection.)